# How to remove a item from a def list in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I am trying to remove a item from a list. I have a table named InvItem and another table named InvItemLoc. When I add a item then the id of InvItem table is used as foreign key in InvItemLoc table. But when I delete a item the child table row is not deleted. Now I need to generate a list of InvItemLoc table by the InvItem id that is currently in InvItem table and with a specific organization. But when I am going to check that if it matches the InvItemLoc with InvItem table it is giving this error:

`No row with the given identifier exists: [inv.InvItem#9666]`

Here is my attempt below:

```
def items = InvItemLoc.findAllByAaOrgId(aaOrg)
                List<InvItemLoc> found = new ArrayList<InvItemLoc>();
                for(InvItemLoc item : items){
                    def invItem = InvItem.findById(item.invItemId.id)
                    if(!invItem){
                        found.add(item);
                    }
                }
                items.removeAll(found);
```

it is giving error at this line:

`def invItem = InvItem.findById(item.invItemId.id)`

### Edit

My InvItemLoc domain looks like this:

```
class InvItemLoc {
    static mapping = {
        ...
    }

    Long id
    InvItem invItemId
    ...

    static constraints = {
        ...

    }
}
```

InvItem domain look likes this:

```
    class InvItem  {
    static mapping = {
        ...
    }
    
    Long id
    ...

    static constraints = {
        ...
    }

        String toString() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from a bi-directional association between `InvItem` and `InvItemLoc`. What do your domain classes look like?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa thanks for your reply. I have updated my post with domain class. Can you please help now ?!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [one-to-many](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-associations/#onetomany) association between the domain classes. Grails can then delete the children for you when you delete the parent. `InvItemLoc` needs the `belongsTo` static property added anx the `invItemId` property removed. `InvItem` needs the *hasMany* static property added.

```
class InvItemLoc {
   ...
   static belongsTo = [item: InvItem]
}

class InvItem  {
    static hasMany = [locations: InvItemLoc]
    ...

}
```

## Creating

This changes the way the domain classes are created and saved.

```
def loc = new InvItemLoc()
// set loc properties.

def item = new InvItem()
item.addToLocations(loc)
// Set other item properties.

item.save()
```

In short, you add the locations to the item, then save the item, which in turn saves the locations.

## Deleting

Then, you can delete simply like this: `item.delete()`